# c# split into variables

Tags: c#, android, string, xamarin

So the thing is I'm getting the data over bluetooth the mobile app in xamarin. On Input I receive the set of values every 1000 milisecond. 
For example -44 -12 -1024 and I want them to be on my screen showed with the updates. But I'm getting the error during splitting income string in 3 variables

```
              _myConnection.ThisSocket.InputStream.Read(read, 0, 1);
               _myConnection.ThisSocket.InputStream.Close();
                String DispString = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(read);
                string newstring = DispString;    
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    string[] CommString = newstring.Split(' ');
                    foreach (string var in CommString)
                    {
                        x = CommString[0];
                        y = CommString[1]; //exception is here (Out of range)
                        z = CommString[2];
                    }
                    int newx = (int)Convert.ToDouble(x);
                    int newy = (int)Convert.ToDouble(y);
                    int newz = (int)Convert.ToDouble(z);

                    JustLabel.Text = ("value is "+newx+" "+newy+" "+newz);

                });
```

Comment: 1. Why converting to double, casting to int, and then convert to string again? This makes no sense. 2. You are getting an out of range exception when the string does not contain a space. Probably not all strings comes with 3 values. At least one of them (the one causing the error) comes with only a single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defensive programming 101

> Don't ever trust anyones code or data, and definitely don't trust your
>   own

How to rectify your problem?

```
string[] CommString = newstring.Split(' ');

// Sanity Check
if(CommString.Length < 3)
{
   // oh no's!!!!

   // log
   // throw
   // writeline

   // somehow deal with it
}
else
{
   x = CommString[0];
   y = CommString[1]; 
   z = CommString[2];
}
```